# How to parse output in Python and use it in loop

Tags: python, paramiko

I need to extract 'xe-1/2/0' from the following UPD.result output:

```
interface xe-1/2/0.0;
interface ge-1/2/1.0;
interface lo0.0 {
```

(This is output from 'show configuration protocols ospf| match int' command) from one box in a list.)

---

I'm using a netmiko library to connect to network devices and find some interfaces that is particulating in OSPF protocol, then I want to check errors count on this interfaces.

```
import getpass
import sys
import time
import textfsm
import os
from tabulate import tabulate
import re


from netmiko import ConnectHandler

USER = raw_input("Login:")
PASSWORD = getpass.getpass()
FILENAME = raw_input("Name of file with results:")
GETPATH= os.getcwd()
GETPATH2 = (GETPATH+'/IP-ADD.txt')
GETPATH3 = (GETPATH+'/template-desc.template')

BOXES_IP = [line.strip() for line in open(GETPATH2, 'r')]
print(BOXES_IP)

for IP in BOXES_IP:
    print('CONNECTION TO DEVICE {}'.format(IP))
    try:
       DEVICE_PARAMS = {'device_type': 'juniper_junos',
                        'ip': IP,
                        'username':USER,
                        'password':PASSWORD,
                        'verbose': True}
        with ConnectHandler(**DEVICE_PARAMS) as sss:
            sss.enable()

            result = sss.send_command('show configuration protocols ospf| match int')
            hostname = sss.send_command('show configuration system host-name')
            print(result)
    except:
        print('CONNECTION TO DEVICE FAILS {}'.format(IP))
        continue

    f = open(FILENAME+'.txt', 'a')
    for row in hostname:
        f.write(row)
    for row in result:
        f.write(row)
    f.close()

    regex = re.compile(r'^(xe.[0-9].[0-9].[0-9])')
    results_list = [] 

    b = open(FILENAME+'.txt', 'r')
    print b
    for line in b:
        match = regex.search(line)
        if not match: continue
        results_list.append(match.group())
    print results_list
```

I need to parse the output of command `'show configuration protocols ospf| match int'` and find `xe` (e.g. `xe-0/0/1`) interfaces and after that enter the `'show interface xe-*** extensive'` command and print results in a file.

How can I do this?

I'm trying to parse output file with compile but it doesn't work.

UPDATE.

```
print(result)
```

output:

```
interface lo0.0 {
interface xe-1/3/1.0;
interface ge-1/2/0.0;
interface xe-1/3/0.0;
```

Result of split

```
    for l in result.split("\n"):
    l = l.split(" ")
    print l

[u'']
[u'', u'', u'', u'', u'interface', u'lo0.0', u'{']
[u'', u'', u'', u'', u'interface', u'xe-1/3/1.0;']
[u'', u'', u'', u'', u'interface', u'ge-1/2/0.0;']
[u'', u'', u'', u'', u'interface', u'xe-1/3/0.0;']
[u'']
```

Comment: Maybe you could include examples of input an desired output?

Comment: @zipa updated main post

Comment: We don't need to see or understand any of your paramiko code. All we need to see is the input and desired output. I rewrote your question to hoist that to the top.

Comment: Why should we exclude interface 'lo0.0' but include 'xe-1/2/0.0' and 'ge-1/2/1.0'? What's the pattern for legitimate network interface names?

Comment: @smci all interfaces that we needed is started with 'ge-*/*/*' or 'xe-*/*/*'.

'lo0' is logical interface which dont need to manipulate with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, regexp is overkill and error prone for this task. 
I would do something like:

```
result ="""interface xe-1/2/0.0;
interface ge-1/2/1.0;
interface lo0.0 {
"""

for l in result.split("\n"):
    l = l.split(" ")
    if l[0] == "interface": # cause grep on "int"
        iface = l[1]
        if iface[0:3] == "xe-":
            arg=iface.split(".")[0]
            # do something with arg
            print(arg)
```

produces :

```
xe-1/2/0
```

Comment: After we splint("\n") list look like this:
a = [u'', u'    interface ge-1/2/0.0;', u'    interface ge-1/2/1.0;', u'    interface lo0.0 {', u'']

Comment: @Goroshek, probably, but it does not change the answer : empty lines will be  ignored.

Comment: It doesnt work for me now, but i understand the idea. thanks

Comment: @Goroshek, if you provide your input, we may find the issue

Comment: Check out the UPDATE section

Comment: if lines of the result start with space, you can use `str.strip()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `re` this should do it:

```
import re

output = '''interface xe-1/2/0.0;
interface ge-1/2/1.0;
interface lo0.0 {'''

print(re.findall('xe-\d/\d/\d', output))
#['xe-1/2/0']
```

To get to desired output, you can use:

```
for found in re.findall('xe-\d/\d/\d', output):
    print('show interface {} extensive'.format(found))
```

Comment: got this
[u'xe-1/3/1', u'xe-1/3/0']
Dont really know from where this u' symbols are coming

Comment: @Setop First line of the question states that OP wants only `xe`

Comment: @Goroshek `u'some_text'` only indicates that the text is unicode, it's nothing you should worry about (if it doesn't produce errors later in code).